# Do validations still fire in ASP.NET even if the controls are hidden?

Tags: asp.net, validation

I have a form that uses ASP.NET validations. I am using some inline C# in the aspx to show/hide certain controls depending on a user's role. I would use the Visible property, but there are so many of them, I just decided to do inline C# to show and hide (I know, not best practice, but bear with me for a second). I am having an issue where Page.IsValid is always set to False when I submit my form (when certain fields are being hidden).

Will the validations still fire off even if the controls are not even rendered on the page? Also, if this is not the case, is there an effective way of breaking down Page.IsValid to find out what is setting it to False?

Comment: what do you mean by inline c#? Are you setting display: none? Not very clear for me what you're doing

Comment: <% if (newClubRequest) %>
    -- show certain html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you set Visible to false, validation for that control will **not** fire.  From [ASP.Net Validation in Depth](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479045.aspx#aspplusvalid_properties):

> Why not just use Visible=false to have
>   an invisible validator? In ASP.NET the
>   Visible property of a control has a
>   very strong meaning: a control with
>   Visible=false will not be processed at
>   all for pre-rendering or rendering. As
>   a result of this stronger meaning,
>   Visible=false for a validator means
>   that not only does not it not display
>   anything, it is does not function
>   either. It is not evaluated, does not
>   affect page validity, and does not put
>   errors in the summary.

If you want a control to validate but have it hidden on the page, use CSS to set display to none.

Comment: Thanks for the response. This totally makes sense. Do I need to set the Visible property on the validation and the actual control itself? Or just the validation? I am a little flustered with this since my page is doing a PostBack and I have about 10 required field validators (hidden) that are not getting fired off. If you just hide the HTML using CSS, does it only fire off the custom/server-side validations? Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

The validators would still fire, you need to hide them as well

Comment: so you are saying that I need to set the Visible property to false on all of them?

Comment: yes, if you are on a databound context you can bind the visibility to a property.  <asp:RequiredFieldValidator Visible='<%# ShowValidatos>'

Comment: Okay thanks. The only thing is that I would guess if the validations are getting fired behind the scenes, that the required field validators would prevent the form from even being submitted at all (which isn't the case on my end). Any ideas?

Comment: Yes its weird i just make testpage with a requiredfieldvalidator and an invisible textbox and the page gets submitted and after the postback the ErrorMessage appears

Answer (score 1):

The control validation does not fire if what it is trying to validate is invisible.  visible="false"

It will however still validate it you instead do hidden="true" on that control so that it doesn't display to the user but want it to validate it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the validators will fire if they are hidden on client-side.

If a validator and it's control are hidden on client-side by using display="none" or visibility="hidden" CSS attribute, then the validator will still fire both on client-side and server-side.

If you want validators to not evaluate/fire on client-side and server-side, you must set either of these properties on the validators in code-behind:   `Visible="false"` or `Enabled="false"`