# RequiredFieldValidator IsValid returning false on visible = false control

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I want that when the textbox is `visible = false`, the RequiredFieldValidator shouldn't run.

This is my aspx code:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtAmt" MaxLength="7" Style="width: 100px;"/>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ValidationGroup="ln" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtAmt"
                        Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Required" />
```

Now in my code behind

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
           txtAmt.Visible = false;
        }
    }
```

and yet in my button click handler, when I do a `Page.IsValid`, it returns `false` if textbox is empty. Any idea how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just assign an ID to the validator and  disable it.

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
           txtAmt.Visible = false;

         if(!txtAmt.visible) { txtamtValidator.Enabled=false};

        }
    }
```

Comment: I guess this is a hack because Page.IsValid should return true if control's visibility is false as per this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2962280/do-validations-still-fire-in-asp-net-even-if-the-controls-are-hidden I think the original cause of this error is yet to find out.

Comment: You can try to disable the validatorID, or just make both of them visible=false, the control and the validator so they won't be rendered

Answer (score 0):

using javascript you can achive this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function txtAmtOff()
        {
            document.getElementById("txtAmt").style.display = 'none';
            ValidatorEnable(document.getElementById("txtAmtValidator"), false);
        }
        function txtAmtOn()
        {
            document.getElementById("txtAmt").style.display = 'inline';
            ValidatorEnable(document.getElementById("txtAmtValidator"), true);
        }
    </script>
```