# asp:requiredfieldvalidator display error if initial value is still there? (Watermark)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using a asp:requiredfieldvalidator and a watermarked text that says "Enter Address".  I want this validator to fire if that text is still there.  This is what I have and I am stumped on this.  Thanks.

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="Address" Width="150px" onfocus="WaterMark(this, event);"/>                                          
<asp:requiredfieldvalidator ID="RequiredfieldvalidatorAddress" runat="server" ValidationGroup="Group" Display="Dynamic" SetFocusOnError="true" ControlToValidate="Address" Text="Please Enter Your Address"/>
```

I am using C# 2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the InitialValue of the RequiredFieldValidator as the WatermarkText. Modify the markup of your requiredfieldvalidator like below and see if it helps.

```
<asp:requiredfieldvalidator ID="RequiredfieldvalidatorAddress" runat="server" ValidationGroup="Group" Display="Dynamic" SetFocusOnError="true" ControlToValidate="Address" Text="Please Enter Your Address" InitialValue="Enter Address"/>
```

Comment: That will not fire if that watermarked text is there.  I want it to fire if it is still there.

Comment: @user2800287 Yes that's why i am asking you to use Initial Value property

Comment: Ok I read it wrong.  Sorry.  Will the RequiredFieldValidator fire if the textbox is not visible?  That is one of the issues.  Cause it still fires when it is not visible.

Comment: Yes It will fire validation when visible is false

Comment: Please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16412265/requiredfieldvalidator-isvalid-returning-false-on-visible-false-control

Answer (score 1):

You can use [CustomValidators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for Address,  On server validation event of custom validator you can check such below:

**Server Side:**

```
void ServerValidation (object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
 {
       args.IsValid = !Address.Text == "Enter Address";
 }
```

**Client Side:**

```
<script language="javascript"> 
   function ClientValidate(source, arguments)
   {
        var textBox = document.getElementById('<%=Address.ClientID%>');
        if (textBox.value !== "Enter Address" ){
            arguments.IsValid = (args.value !== "");
        } else {
            arguments.IsValid = false;
        }
   }
</script>
```

Hope this helps.